# React Router URL parameter in URL format

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Not sure how to really word the question, but I have tried and not been able to do this properly. I am going to assume that I have to use some sort of regular expression but again, my previous attempts have failed.

What I am looking to do is use react router on specific routes, but I want the URL parameters to be a path itself. For example. I want to have something like

```
<HashRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/page/:thePath" component={ThePageComponent} />
  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

So if I visit a path like http://localhost:9000/#/page/some/random/path/here I can load `ThePageComponent` and access the URL parameters to get `/some/random/path` but it seems to not be able to find the route when I try to set this up.

Can someone point me in the right direction of the docs so I can learn how to do this? I am relatively new to react and react-router so I may be missing something simple but I can't for the life of me figure this out.

Thank you

---

Based on the accepted answer below, I was able to get it working. Its a little different than what I had in the example, but still works

```
<HashRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/*" element={<App/>} />
  </Routes>
</HashRouter>
```

Then in my App component

```
const parameters= useParams();
console.log("params ", parameters)
```

So visiting http://localhost:9000/#/Logic1/Testing will result in the following payload

```
{
    "*": "Logic1/Testing"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [one-or-more parameter](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#one-or-more) `+` at the end of the path to match to the end of the path into the `thePath` match param.

```
<Route path="/page/:thePath+" component={ThePageComponent} />
```

Demo

[image: Edit react-router-url-parameter-in-url-format]

If you want to learn more about [path](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string) matching, RRDv5 uses [path-to-regex@v1.7.0](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) to convert the specified path string into a regex used for route matching.